# Json Operation Serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, enums, json.net, function-pointers

I'm trying to create a Json Parser for C# for use with Unity.  Currently I'm using Json.net as the serializer and I'm having a bit of trouble.  Essentially, in order to deserialize into a function, I'm using an Enum as a representation of a function pointer.  the underlying code is working fine, but I'm having trouble getting the enum to map.

Essentially the object that would be created from the JSON string

```
"{'==': [1, 1]}"
```

would be

```
new Tuple<Enum, dynamic[]>(Enum.Equals, {1, 1})
```

and vice versa.

I have found this resource, but I don't think it goes quite far enough in its explanation: https://bytefish.de/blog/enums_json_net/

Essentially how do I set up Item 1 of the Tuple to be the name of Array Item 2?

Answer (score 0):

One way to see JSON is as a combination of HashMaps (dictionaries), arrays and values.

When you parse a JSON into an object, that object is a combination of dictionaries, arrays, and values.

One way to represent an enum in JSON could be as follow:

`{ 
  "type": "string",
  "enum: ["red", "blue", "yellow"]
}`

So, perhaps you wish to extend the functionality of the library you are using to work with Tuples.

If I am not clear, please let me know.

Comment: Essentially, the serializer currently serializes each item in the Tuple as its own Jarray, so, for the example above, new Tuple<Enum, dynamic[]>(Enum.Equals, {1, 1}), it would serialize to "{'Item1': [1], 'Item2': [1, 1]}" (enum seems to be printed as its equivalent int, but one problem at a time), I need it to serialize as "{'Item1': 'Item2'}"

Comment: @TomPollack Therefore, you need to convert your Tuple into a HashMap so the one element: key:"Item1" and value: "Item2" will be converted into the JSON.

Or, modify the code so it does the conversion of Tuple into HashMap prior to convert to JSON.

Comment: @TomPollack try to see if C# has a method for your tuple called "ToDictionary"

    var map = myTuple.ToDictionary(l => l.Item1, l => l.Item2);